# Corona SDK - APP Doesnt work on Android

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, event-listener

Someone could help me, I made a game in Corona and works perfectly on the simulator, but when I install the Android does not work, the functions are not called. Follow the project https://github.com/AndreRavagnani/SamuraiTheRevenge

Thanks

Comment: Questions on stackoverflow must show what you have tried and why it didnt work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't requiring anything in your main.lua file.  Also what I would recommend doing is using ADB logcat to see what error is happening on the device.  Most likely it's a syntax error that only occurs on build.  Plug your android device into your computer and run logcat to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the simulator but not working on your device, then these could be the few possible errors.

1. Check the file names are proper, because corona is case sensitive, simulator wont care about the spellings but device will throw error.
2. Check whether you are giving the proper scene name, this also case sensitive.
3. Check whether you are giving the proper file path .

I hope if you check these things it will give you some solution.